# Is it possible to use mouse and keyboard through HP USB-C Dock G5 with notebook and another PC

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, mouse, docking-station, usb-c

I have hp notebook and I use mouse and keyboard through HP USB-C Dock G5 with this notebook. All works fine. Then I have a desktop PC as well, which is separate device. My question is, is it somehow possible to connect the mouse and keyboard I am using with my notebook through the G5 with the PC too? The goal is to have just one mouse and just one keyboard for both, notebook and PC. Both devices use Windows 10. Thanks!

Comment: Microsoft has software to do what you want>>>>>https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35460

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That ain't gong to work.
USB uses a **single** controlling device (the so-called "host") which controls everything  connected to that USB bus. All other devices on the bus can only talk to the host and to nothing else.
A computer is always the host. Connecting a second computer, connects a second host and this is simply not supported in the USB world.

What you need is a so-called KVM (Keyboard, Video, Mouse) switch that supports USB.
A USB capable KVM acts towards BOTH hosts as a set of connected devices. It uses for each host a sperate USB bus to do that, so both hosts don't interfere with each other. But towards the devices themselves it looks as if the KVM itself is a single host (using a 3rd USB bus).

Comment: So finally I decided to use [ATEN switch](https://www.aten.com/global/en/products/usb-&-thunderbolt/peripheral-switches/us234/). Thanks!